# How to know which data type is being passed

Tags: select, types, boolean, labview, custom-data-type

I have a `Select` function in my block diagram. For the True and False statements I am passing two data types. The True statement is a is a `Digital Reference` data type to a numerical indicator in the front panel, and the False statement is a `knob Reference` data type to a gauge in the front panel as well. I am not sure what to put in the middle entry point for the `Select` function since it needs to have a True Boolean. Ideally I would just connect another `Digital Reference` data type and it would return the digital indicator in that case but the `Select` function only receives a boolean as an input.

Comment: Please post your code here, it may be easier to help. It seems you are trying to use Select function in an inappropriate way.
https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361R-01/glang/select/

Comment: Could you use a case structure instead of the select function?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve? Why do you want to select one or the other of the references and what do you want to do with the selected one? It will be much easier for people to help you, and maybe there's a better way than using the Select function.

Answer (score 3):

> Ideally I would just connect another Digital Reference data type and it would return the digital indicator in that case

In what case? You haven't defined any case. :-)

The Select node picks between two different *values*. When you wire the digital reference to one input and the knob reference to the other input, the output will be a control reference to one of those two controls. You have to wire a Bool in order to pick which control you're going to operate on downstream.

You say you want to wire another Digital Reference to the middle terminal, but that's just a reference to a control. It doesn't define a choice. Perhaps you want to read the Value property of that other control and do something on the value? If so, this is your code, where you put whatever test you want instead of the Equal Zero node.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select function requires a boolean in the selector input. The other two inputs changes according to what you connect.
So, in your scenario:

- Output type is the most lower common class between knob reference and numeric reference. It should be a Numeric reference.
- the selector input must be a boolean type. You cannot connect any reference or any other data type. So, connect a boolean control or use the approach suggested by srm.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by connecting an `equal` function to the middle boolean selector input of the `select` function. The `equal` function has two inputs, an either `Knob Reference` or `Digital Reference` for the first input and a `Digital Reference` for the second input. If those two are equal then the `equal` function passes true to the `selector` function and then the `Digital Reference` gets passed in this case.

Comment: Do you understand that the Equals will NEVER be true in the code you described? The knob reference is never equal to the digital reference. The *values* of those references are not the same as the references. It’s akin to comparing “c == a” or “&c == &a”. The latter will never be true.

Comment: @srm Please note that I specified "The equal function has two inputs, an either Knob Reference or Digital Reference for the first input and a Digital Reference for the second input" which means that it will vary in every case. The VI is within a loop which changes the input to the equal statement every time.

Comment: This would be a lot clearer if you posted a picture of your code.